# Не выводится буквально ничего

Tags: c++

Есть код, который заполняет двумерный вектор из текстового файла.

Код:

```
    vector <vector <string>> create_array_from_file(ifstream& f, string& text)
{
    vector <string> array1 = {};    
    vector <vector <string>> array = {};    
    char c;
    array1.resize(10);
    array.resize(2, array1);

    while (f.get(c))
    {
        if (c != '\n')
        {
            getline(f, text, ' ');
            array1.push_back(text);
        }
        else
        {
            array.push_back(array1);
            array1.clear();
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Функция вывода содержимого веектора:

```
    void print_array(vector <vector <string>> array, int strs, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strs; i++)  
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)  
        {
            cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Текстовый файл:

```
1 Крузенштерн Акакий Акакиевич 367806 5 4 3 2 1
2 Жмышенко Валерий Альбертович 367807 0 2 1 5 3
```

Одномерный вектор должен состоять из элементов строки (разделитель - пробел), двумерный вектор должен состоять из этих самых одномерных векторов. То есть, элемент array[0][1] должен быть "Крузенштерн".

При выводе почему-то ничего не выводится, ошибок никаких не выдаёт. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: ваш `getline(f, text, ' ');` с разделителем пробелом `' '` игнорирует перенос строки и команда `getline` проглатывает этот перенос как одно слово. *после `f.get(c)` желательно вернуть букву в поток `f.unget();`.*

Comment: может быть поможет считать одну строку с разделителем переноса строки `'\\n'`. и потом считать отдельно по словам с помощью класса `sstream`?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, то есть, без f.get()?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, способ с sstream помог. но что-то я не могу отметить этот коммент как решение вопроса) может, потому что он написан в комментарии, а не в ответы?